# IE11: Search functionality with autosuggestion - IE11 fails to understand 'Enter' key is pressed

Tags: javascript

I know this has been asked many times and I tried many solutions nothing seems to work. In my application, I have autosuggestion functionality written in javascript.
In which, if i start to write a term in search box, it appends the suggestions with the URL to the suggested products. On IE11, When I use 'down' key to select a product and enter it doesn't seem to recognise that 'Enter' key has been pressed and never goes in the method where it checks if the 'event.which === 13' hence doesn't work. I am attaching the piece of code (cant attach whole function as is) any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```js
  $('.searchInput').on('keyup', e => {
      const upKey = 38;
      const downKey = 40;
      const enterKey = 13;
      if (e.which === enterKey) {
        window.location.href = 'url to the product';
      }
    });
```

```html
<form id="searchBox">  
    <input type="text" name="searchTerm" class="searchInput" autocomplete="off">
    <button type="submit" class="icon-icon_search --active"></button>
    <div class="c-header__search-suggestions" data-searchlimit="7">
      <ul class="c-header__search-suggestions-list">
        <li class="c-header__search-suggestions-product">
                <a class="c-header__search-suggestions-item" href="<"URL_to_the_product_where_it_should_redirect_on_selection>">
                 <span class="c-header__search-suggestions-item-keyword">bo</span>ni
    </a>
            </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'd expect this to happen in any browser, but the issue is not that the event handler wouldn't be called. Hitting ENTER on a text field in a form submits the form by default, and the pending form submission prevents JS to change the location. Put `e.preventDefault()` just before redirecting, that prevents the form being submitted.

Comment: Thanks Teemu for your answer. Its actually working in other browsers without 'e.preventDefault()'. However I tried this in IE11, it didn't work. In my code I tried it before 'window.location.href'. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is odd, the code really seems to work in other browsers. To prevent the default action, you'd need `keydown`, `keyup` doesn't have a default action. If you change the event type, preventDefault might work in IE too.

Comment: @Teemu: Changing the event to 'keydown' with 'e.preventDefault()' worked!! I had tried it earlier but not both together. Thank you so much :)